# Why are my users not getting an email when order is completed?

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I have the "Send e-mail notification on update." checked and I click Update but no email is sent to the user.

```
Trigger: E-mail requested for order status update

Conditions:
Operator: AND

Condition (1): Check the order status
Arguments: Order
Negate this Condition is checked
Order Status: In Checkout

Condition (2): 
Date - check the current date
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had some problems with spam filters before. Usually I use the [SMTP Authentication Support module](https://drupal.org/project/smtp) module to avoid them.

It's fairly easy to use, you just have to have access to a smtp mail server (for example a gmail account) and configure your settings (varies between different servers).